# How to Change poedit GUI/menu language?

Tags: gui, language-support

I installed **Poedit** using

```
sudo apt-get install poedit
```

my linux default language is Persian(Farsi) so poedit installed with a Persian GUI (menus and etc) interface.
but for some reason I want my poedit interface to be English.
How can I change Poedit interface language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**salam**

You can always create a bash script and change your language before running `poedit` or any program for that matter. for example if `poedit` runs with command `/usr/bin/poedit`, you can create a script file with these lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
exec /usr/bin/poedit $@
```

Comment: thanks. but it didn't worked! after copying your code in .sh file and executing it poedit started with Persian GUI again!

Comment: Update: I fixed it by editing your code! ... the correct code in line 2 is: `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` ... thanks again

Comment: @MahdiAryayi you are welcome. I edited my post to avoid confusion as well.